# Replacing a hard drive in a mirror on a SAS6iR card with a non-Dell purchased drive

Tags: dell, seagate

Does anyone know if the Dell SAS6IR cards that were sold around April of last year will still take off the shelf Seagate SATA drives or do they have to be purchased from Dell to be recognized?  I know they've started doing that with some cards but not sure of the transition date.  As luck would have it I need to replace a drive right away and don't want to wait for Dell to ship the part (and pay the Dell tax to boot).

Answer (score 0):

Well, just to report back, I went ahead and threw a standard off-the-shelf Seagate Constellation drive into this array and it was recognized fine, so no Dell-approved lockout.  Can't speak to newer controllers, but April 2010 and before should be fine.